# struct initialization / assignment with braces

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

I have defined a struct as follows:

```
struct float3 {
float x; 
float y;
float z;

float3 () : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
float3 (float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
};
```

But i have trouble when it comes to understanding the different ways of initializing / assigning values to its members. For instance:

```
//Initialization
float3 3Dvec = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
float3 3Dvec2 {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
float3 3Dvec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

//Assignment
3Dvec = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0};
3Dvec = float3 (2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
```

All of these options do work with -std=c++11. However on an older compiler with -std=c++0x braces initialization / assignment does not work. Is usign braces a bad practice? Which option is better to get used to?

Comment: You should write code to either of the C++11 or C++03 standards, not some half-way point (which your older compiler seems to be.) What you are showing here looks like good C++11 practice.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'd disagree here; why not make the most out of the compiler you have available by using those C++11 features it supports. For example, we're using gcc 4.8 and VS 2010 at work; should we resign on lambdas, smart pointers, `auto` and move semantics simply because VS2010 doesn't support `constexpr`?

Comment: @Angew If you are fully in control of your half-way point compilers, then fine. Otherwise it is too ill-defined for portability. That is what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @juanchopanza Alright, that's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, all of these are legal. If you know you'll be working with a C++11-compliant compiler (at least as far as list initialisation is concerned), I'd say it's preferable to use the brace syntax. It's future-proof and unambiguous.

Here's a detailed analysis of the individual statements:

```
float3 vec3D = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
```

Copy-list-initialisation. Strictly by the book, this creates a temporary `float3` by calling its 3-parameter constructor, then initialises `vec3D` by using the move constructor (or copy constructor, if no move ctor is available), and finally destroys the temporary.

In practice, the temporary creation and move/copy operation will be elided by any non-broken compiler, so there is no inefficiency. *However,* note that it requires the move/copy constructor to be accessible. You cannot initialise a non-movable, non-copyable class like this, for example.

```
float3 vec3D2 {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
float3 vec3D3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Both of these directly initialise `vec3D2` by calling its 3-parameter constructor. I'd say the brace one is the optimal syntax, because it's unambiguous. In this particular case, it does not matter, but sometimes, using parentheses can lead to a [(most) vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)<sup>1</sup>.

```
vec3D = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0};
vec3D = float3 (2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
```

These are 100% identical, as long as the type of `vec3D` is `float3`. Both create a temporary `float3` object using its 3-parameter constructor, pass that object to the move (or copy) assignment operator of `vec3D`, and then destroy the temporary.

I'd say the brace one is better, because it's future proof. If you later rename the class, the brace one will continue to work as is, while the parenthesis one will require a name chaage. Also, if you change the type of `vec3D`, the brace one will still create an object of `vec3D`'s type, while the second one will keep creating and assigning from a `float3` object. It's not possible to say universally, but I'd say the former behaviour is usually preferred.

---

<sup>1</sup> An example of that would be:

```
float3 x(float3());  // a function
//vs.
float3 y{float3{}};  // a variable
```