# Struct Initialization Error

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I know how to initialize structs (generally), but I'm having troubles with this 
struct within a struct stuff

```
typedef struct Location{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
} loc;

typedef struct Person{
    loc location;
} person;
```

global variables:

```
static person hero;
```

initialization functions:

```
void InitializeHero() {
    person hero = {0,0, {0,0}}; // this compiles
    hero.location = {0,0}; // but this does not compile
    hero = {0,0,{0,0}}; // this also does not compile
}
```

Comment: Huh? Your first initialization does *not* compile. You have 4 scalars inside `{ }` and only 2 scalar members in the struct. This is an error in C.

Comment: More or less a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24138140/694576

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c)

Comment: Ah yes my apologies. I'm new to Stack Overflow and when I was editing my code to make the syntax fit with how the system wanted it I must have accidentally deleted part of the struct. The struct Person initially had 4 scalar members {uint8_t x; uint8_t y; loc location}

Answer (score 3):

Your 'this compiles' line is correct; that's an initialization. The other two lines don't compile, because they're not initializations, they're assignments. If you're using a new enough version of C, you could use a compound literal to do the assignments:

```
hero.location = (loc){0,0};
hero = (person){0,0,{0,0}};
```

Note - your `person hero` declaration in `InitializeHero` shadows the global variable; you probably don't want that.

BTW, are you missing some fields in your `person`? None of that should compile with what you've shown.

Comment: Yes my bad. Sorry about the missing fields (are these called scalars?)

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of compound literals? Are they for clarity? Because they seem kind of redundant

Answer (score 1):

The line you indicate that compiles produces a warning. Let's break apart your `InitializeHero` function.

`person hero = {0,0, {0,0}};`

Here you are instantiating your new `person` struct named `hero`. You use the brace initialization method to set the members of the struct. In this case, the only member of `person` is a `loc`. A `loc` itself only has two `uint8_t`s. Using the brace initialization method here, you would simply use `{0, 0}`.

Combining these two, you could write a statement like:

`person hero = {{0, 0}};`

Note that you can only use brace initialization when initializing. Your other two statements are *assignments*. The struct has already been initialized at this point, which is why those two statements don't compile.

One other note, your global variable `static person hero` has been shadowed by the **local** variable `hero` in `InitializeHero`. This means that you are creating a separate `person` struct in your `InitializeHero`. However, this static variable is initialized where it is declared in this case, so your statement must read

`static person hero = {{0, 0}};`

...leaving `InitializeHero` unused.

Comment: The function would still have a purpose if it set the global variable (and therefore did not declare the local variable).  You sometimes need to reinitialize a global variable and a function like that might be appropriate.