# Why cannot i initialize struct like this?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct Employee
{
    int age;
    double wage;
};

Employee joe;
joe = {2,60.0}; //using initialization list instead of doing Employee joe={2,60.0}
```

I am getting a compilation error in Visual Studio 2015, but able to execute in Code blocks using C++ version C++11

Comment: because this is an assignment, not an initialization?  assignment and initialization are two completely different things, despite both being associated with the token `=`.

Comment: This should work (and does work on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/); if it doesn't it's a compiler bug.

Comment: That should definitely work. I just tested it on VS2015 and it was fine. Are you sure that's the error you're getting? Try a new project with just that struct and then that second section in main, nothing else.

Comment: check that you are using the v140 platform toolset

Comment: I observed in Visual Studio 2012 when I run this code:
    struct Employee
    {
            int age;
     double wage;
    };

    int main()
    {
     Employee joe {2,56.0};
     joe = {1,34.0};
    }
the compilation error is there, in which it does not allow me to put braces in the line Employee joe{  and also in next line joe = {.

Comment: Observing that a compiler accepts it is not a signal of something going wrong with yours.  You have to read the standard that applies to your problem and after that, decide if it is behaving well or not.  By the way, an assignment is not an initialization, as @ChrisDodd notices, despite the fact that both are associated with `=` operator.

Answer (score 4):

It should work.

### Copy-list-initialization

The following is valid and is called [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> ```
> joe = {2,60.0};
> ```

It is in fact a temporary on the right hand side that is being initialized. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138229/1460794).

As mentioned in the comments to the provided example, the following would be initialization. More specifically it would **also** be [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). (It *used to be* [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) until c++11, but now braces have been, well, embraced from c++11 onwards):

```
Employee joe={2,60.0}
```

---

### Copy assignment

Or you could use [copy assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment):

```
joe = Employee{2,60.0};
```

---

### Aggregate initialization

You could use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) when you define the variable:

```
Employee joe{2,60.0};
```

---

Comment: "But this tries to assign a std::initializer_list to joe" That's just plain wrong.

Comment: @T.C. Should it still process aggregate initialization here? I tried but can't find quotes about it...

Comment: @song Should aggregate initialize a temporary and then move-assign from it.

Comment: @Barry Got it! Thanks.

Comment: `Employee joe={2,60.0}` is also copy-list-initialization

Comment: @M.M Very true, thank you. The answer still wasn't correct. I've made an update.

Comment: I observed in Visual Studio 2012 when I run this code: 

struct Employee 
{ int age; double wage; }; 

int main() 
{ 
    Employee joe {2,56.0}; 
joe = {1,34.0}; 
} 

the compilation error is there, in which it does not allow me to put braces in the line Employee joe{ and also in next line joe = {.

Comment: @rad123 Ok, that makes sense. Visual studio 2012 [does not support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) initializer lists.

Answer (score 1):

An often used way of initializing correctly a `struct` like yours in C++ is through a proper constructor, like this one:

```
struct Employee
{
    int age;
    double wage;

    Employee(int _age, double _wage): age(_age),wage(_wage) {}
};
```

and then, use it as:

```
Employee joe(2, 60.0); // declaration and initialization.
```